Addicted cop gets clean and seeks revenge
The movie is old maybe from the 70's or 80's. 
A cop who is assigned to investigate a drug dealer group is forced to take drugs through injection and becomes addicted. 
Then the rest of the movie is about how he goes through difficult recovery. Finally he decides to get revenge and sees the head drug dealer on his yacht. 
He chased the yacht by running several kilometers in the harbor to get as close as possible and call the head drug dealer and finally shoot him with a machine gun.   
The head drug dealer has a beard and is thin and wears a suit. 
The film looks like it is European, possibly Italian, but not American. I am not quite sure.  

I suspect this might be The French Connection II (1975) starring Gene Hackman. 

The film expands on the central character of Det. Jimmy "Popeye" Doyle who travels to Marseille, France where he is attempting to track down French drug-dealer Alain Charnier, who got away at the end of the first film. 

Wikipedia

For several weeks, Doyle is injected with heroin in effort to force him into capitulation. Scenes of his growing addiction follow, including one in which an elderly lady (Cathleen Nesbitt) visits him in his befuddled state. She talks to him, declaring herself to be English, and saying that her son is "just like" him, while stroking his arm. Initially she seems compassionate to his plight, but a change in the camera angle reveals her 'track' marks and that she is slowly removing his watch.



Doyle is joined by Barthélémy and other inspectors who engage Charnier's henchmen in a gun battle in a dry dock, which results in water from multiple spillways pouring out. The henchmen and inspectors are killed but Doyle rescues Barthélémy. The following raid on Charnier and his henchmen is successful, but Charnier escapes. Doyle, in a foot chase of Charnier, who is sailing out of the harbor on his yacht, takes his gun out, calls Charnier's name, and finally shoots him dead.


I saw the trailer now . Yes , that is true. thank you very much for your help. (Hasan)

@hasan Dont' forget to accept the answer (click the check mark on the left)
